# How do I get the names of both chooser and chosen in a single report using SQL SELECT?

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many

I want to make a list of pupils choosing other pupils for roommates. They can thus be split into chooser and chosen. In other words, this is a question about how to join two tables with a many-to-many relationship, when one table is referenced twice.

To start off, I've made a table of all the pupils creatively called 'Pupils'...

Then I made a table with two sets of foreign keys referencing the ID's of the pupil's list to denote chooser and chosen. I called it 'Choices' and made the relation many to many.

I end up with two tables:

- Pupils: Fields: id, firstname, lastname, age, sex, class
- Choices: Fields: id, chooser_fk, choice_fk, choice_priority

However I came up short when I tried to report the names of both chooser and chosen using SELECT.

I can't seem to get any further than this:

```
SELECT Pupils.firstname, Pupils.lastname, Choices.choice
FROM Pupils
INNER JOIN Choices
ON Pupils.id=Choices.chooser
WHERE Pupils.sex = 'M';
```

...but this only gets the name for the chooser, and only the ID of the chosen. I tried to search, but the things I found were either irrelevant or too advanced for me to understand properly. Still trying to learn.

I'd like to have the names for both chooser and chosen side by side in the report. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need one reference of `Pupils` for the choosers and another reference of `Pupils` for the choice/chosen:

```
SELECT 
    p1.firstname, p1.lastname, --chooser
    p2.firstname, p2.lastname  --choice/chosen
FROM Pupils p1
INNER JOIN Choices
    ON p1.id=Choices.chooser
INNER JOIN Pupils p2
    ON p2.id=Choices.choice
WHERE p1.sex = 'M'; --or whatever clause makes sense to you
                    --the important concept here is referencing Pupils twice
```

Comment: Thank you, this works! :D Learned something new today. Where can one find stuff like that easily explained like this?

Comment: Here, I guess :-) Glad to help

Answer (score 1):

Just join the table in again for the chooser:

```
SELECT chooser.firstname AS ChooserFirst, chooser.lastname AS ChooserLast, 
       chosen.firstname AS ChosenFirst, chosen.lastname AS ChosenLast, 
FROM Choices AS c
JOIN Pupils AS chooser
  ON chooser.id=c.chooser
JOIN Pupils AS chosen
  on chosen.id=c.chosen
WHERE (chooser.sex = 'M' or chosen.sex ='M');
```

Answer (score 1):

In `JOIN`, if you want two separate rows (in this case Pupils) from the same table, you will need to JOIN it into the query twice, once for the chooser and once for the chosen. That will end up looking something like;

```
SELECT p1.firstname ChooserFN, p1.lastname ChooserLN, 
       p2.firstname ChosenFN,  p2.lastname ChosenLN
FROM Pupils p1
JOIN Choices c ON p1.id = c.chooser
JOIN Pupils p2 ON p2.id = c.chosen
WHERE p1.sex = 'M' OR p2.sex = 'M';
```